# Why can't I get ocaml/opam:ubuntu-16.04_ocaml-4.03.0 docker Image?

Tags: docker, ocaml, opam

I was trying to run:

```
docker build -f hol-light/Dockerfile_check_proofs --ulimit stack=1000000000 --tag check_proofs hol-light/
```

but I get the error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon   48.9MB
Step 1/16 : FROM ocaml/opam:ubuntu-16.04_ocaml-4.03.0
pull access denied for ocaml/opam, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Why?

The docker file is: https://github.com/brain-research/hol-light/blob/master/Dockerfile_check_proofs

```
FROM ocaml/opam:ubuntu-16.04_ocaml-4.03.0
WORKDIR /home/opam/
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ENV PATH="/home/opam/.opam/4.03.0/bin:${PATH}"

### Install num
RUN opam install num

### Install campl5
RUN git clone --depth 1 -b rel617 https://github.com/camlp5/camlp5
RUN cd camlp5 &&\
  ./configure &&\
  make world.opt &&\
  make install &&\
  # meta/Makefile in camlp5 skips these files which we need, so copy them
  # manually.
  cp {main/pcaml,main/quotation,etc/pa_reloc,meta/q_MLast}.{cmi,cmx,o} `camlp5 -where`

### Install grpc
RUN sudo apt-get update &&\
  sudo apt-get install -y build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config clang libc++-dev
RUN git clone -b 'v1.17.1' --recurse-submodule --depth 1 https://github.com/grpc/grpc
RUN sudo make -C grpc install-headers_c install-static_c install-pkg-config_c\
    install-headers_cxx install-static_cxx install-pkg-config_cxx\
    install-plugins
RUN sudo make -C grpc/third_party/protobuf install

### Install farmhash
RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/google/farmhash &&\
  cd farmhash &&\
  ./configure CXXFLAGS="-DNAMESPACE_FOR_HASH_FUNCTIONS=farmhash"
RUN sudo make -C farmhash install

### Build binaries
COPY --chown=opam:0 . src/
RUN make -C src check_proofs
CMD ["./src/check_proofs"]
```

---

crossposted:

- https://forums.docker.com/t/why-cant-i-get-ocaml-opam-ubuntu-16-04-ocaml-4-03-0-docker-image/84351

Answer (score 1):

https://hub.docker.com/r/ocaml/opam/ hasn't been updated for 2 years and says:

> At some point in the future, the tags in this repository will be deleted

This deletion is currently in progress (in fact, it has been deleting for more than a week now).

The `ocaml/opam` (opam 1) images generally aren't useful now because they don't work with the current opam-repository.

There are two alternatives you can use:

- `ocaml/opam2` contains opam 2 images. e.g. `ocaml/opam2:ubuntu-16.04-ocaml-4.03`
- `ocurrent/opam` is also opam 2, but contains much smaller images (with only one version of the compiler per image). e.g. `ocurrent/opam:ubuntu-16.04-ocaml-4.03`
  However, this repository is only temporary. It will replace `ocaml/opam` once Hub finishes deleting that...